# SQL error 1064 - how to fix?

Tags: php, sql

What is this?

```
SQL query: 

ALTER TABLE `ads` ADD `ad_title` VARCHAR NOT NULL 

MySQL said:  
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1
```

Query is generated by phpmyadmin

Comment: Looks like a phpmyadmin bug. Are you running the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error in this sentence lies in the type definition of the column. It should specify the maximum length of the `VARCHAR` column.

```
ALTER TABLE `ads` ADD `ad_title` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
```

It is working in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae529/1).

See the following example, where length 50 is assigned to columns  `First_Name` and `Surname`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign a length for your `VARCHAR`.